# Reverting master version in GC/SVN to a early version (i.e., removing bad versions and starting over)

Tags: svn, google-code

So someone on our team was using TortoiseSVN and made some ten commitments in five minutes (without comments, natuerlich), after which our software stopped working properly.  The rest of us were making commitments in command line, and no problems happened.  I think he was doing things he wasn't aware of, and now we have a cluster of problems we can't seem to resolve.  It was working perfectly at r29, and when one reverts one's local copy to r29, the software behaves as expected.  I won't right now detail all the ways we've tried to solve this problem, but we've so far failed to commit r29 to a new version.  All the commands about reverting don't seem to work with making a NEW version, and the support doesn't seem relevant when there are major changes to the filesystem.

So can you tell me how to checkout an old version and commit it as the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go back to r29 by performing this merge command in a clean working directory (with no files changed):

```
svn merge -rHEAD:29 .
svn commit -m'rolling back to -r29.'
```

What this means is "create a patch formed by the difference between HEAD (latest) and -r29, and apply that patch here."  This effectively reverses all the changes performed since -r29.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to export r29 to one location on your local machine, and check out the head version to another location, and overwrite all the files in head with r29, then commit them. It's a bit hacky, but it should work.

Also, you might be able to do a reverse merge...

Comment: Reverse merge is exactly meant to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

See the [chapter on undoing changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) in the book Version Control with Subversion

e.g to undo change 30:

```
svn merge -c -30 http://path/to/your/repo/trunk
```

What this essentially does, is to create a new commit that reverses the change from r30. There is no undo in a strict sense in Subversion, history is always preserved (and that's a good thing IMO)